# change group ownership specifying from to for entire file system

Tags: permissions, group, chown, chgrp

I have 3 specific user accounts (less than 10 anyway), for all files & folders under a specific `/data` or `/home` directory, I want to change just the group ownership of all occurring files/folders of those specific users.

I don't know where everywhere might be (besides `/home` and `/data`) so I want to do a `<what?> -R` on `/`.  Is there a way to do that?  The existing group is named `XYZ` and I want to change all files & folders that are owned by `ron.XYZ` to `ron.users`.  How can that be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `find` to identify the target files, and then apply the change of group to those.

```
find / -user ron -group XYZ -print -exec chgrp users {} +
```

You can omit the `-print` if you aren't worried about seeing which files are being changed. You can also (temporarily) omit the `-exec … +` if you first want to see which files would be affected before changing them.

You can extend the match to all three user accounts at once:

```
find / \( -user ron -o -user alice -o -user bob \) -group XYZ -print -exec chgrp users {} +
```

Note that you will descend into `/proc` (and other pseudo filesystems). You can safely ignore errors about changing ownerships there. You can use `-prune` to omit such filesystems:

```
find / \( -path /proc -o -path /dev -o -path /sys \) -prune -o …as above…
```

Comment: thanks,  this worked well; I just used your first example and let it squawk for 3 seconds about `/proc`